# React - TypeScript - Uncaught TypeError: setSearchQuery is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, typeerror

I am getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: setSearchQuery is not a function` in Next.js / Typescript app where I am typing a search query inside search box. I created a generic search function in TypeScript and all my code works well expect I am getting this tiny error... Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

`TopPanel.tsx`

```
  export interface ISearchInputProps {
  setSearchQuery: (searchQuery: string) => void; 

  export const TopPanel = (props: ISearchInputProps) => {
    const { setSearchQuery } = props;
    return (
        <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search Assets..."
              onChange={(event) => 
                setSearchQuery(event.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
        );
       }
```

`AssetsList.tsx`

`````
 import generiSearch from 'src/utils/genericSearch' 

 const [query] = useState<string>('');````

 const filteredData = reserves
    .filter((res) => genericSearch(res, ['symbol'], query, false))
    .map((reserve) => ({
      ...rest of the code...
    }));

    return (
     ... 
   );
  }
`````

`genericSearch.ts`

```
export default function genericSearch<T>(
  object: T,
  properties: Array<keyof T>,
  query: string,
  shouldBeCaseSensitive: boolean
): boolean {
  if (query === '') {
    return true;
  }

  const expression = properties.map((property) => {
    const value = object[property];

    if (typeof value === 'string' || typeof value === 'number') {
      if (shouldBeCaseSensitive) {
        return value.toString().includes(query);
      } else {
        return value.toString().toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase());
      }
    }

    return false;
  });
  return expression.some((expression) => expression);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the part of the code where you call TopPanel component?

Comment: I'm guessing that the problem is going to be where you call `TopPanel` you don't provide the `setSearchQuery` prop like `<TopPanel setSearchQuery={() => 123} />`. But that part of your code has not been posted, so we can only speculate.

Comment: Yes! Omg! I knew the error is tiny! Yes! When I opened the page where TopPanel is imported, I could see the error! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking, the problem is that you call `setSearchQuery` in `TopPanel` without props definition. `ISearchInputProps` is only interface.

Comment: Thank you! You were correct! I fixed the error! I knew it was so tiny! :)